# Can “alma mater” refer to any school you’ve graduated from, not just college?

Tags: meaning, latin

I was wondering whether *alma mater* refers to all the schools you have been in, or just to college.

For example, suppose someone has an undergranduate degree from one institution, a masters degree from another, and a PhD from yet a third; would all three of those count as his *alma mater*?

Comment: _Foster Mother_. From Latin.

Comment: ok, but how is it used nowadays?

Comment: @JohnLawler: Yes, but in the sense of "feeding", not necessarily "adoptive".

Comment: **MW**: a school (as a college or university) which one has attended and usually from which one has graduated.

Comment: I was just researching this topic for personal reasons. "Alma mater" is almost exclusively used for baccalaureate programs. I found example that used Harvard Law School, but that page uses Harvard in all their examples. I couldn't find any other examples of graduate programs referred to as alma maters--Can they be? Or do people just usually not have that much of an emotional connection to their grad programs to use that terminology for those schools?

Comment: If this question is closed because it's too basic and can be answered by a single link, where is that link? The accepted answer has not addressed the issue of graduate schools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is normally only used for a college or university, not for a high school; the last would sound a bit silly and pretentious. However, silly and pretentious can be humorous, so talking about your primary school as your alma mater can be appropriate if you are being ironic.

Comment: This is becoming a relatively common practice on Monday Night Football here in the U.S. They have a tradition of "introducing" each team's starters with a video snippet, where the player states his name and alma mater (e.g., "Tony Romo, Eastern Illinois University"). Some time back, a few players started saying the names of their high school instead (e.g., "Andy Dalton, Katy High School"). As that practice was copied more and more, a few players took it one step further in the humor department; I've heard some players say the likes of, "John Smith, Westover Elementary."

Comment: @J.R.: Hah, that's great! Next will be kindergartens...

Answer (score 0):

It is usually used to describe a school or college from which an individual has graduated or which they have attended.